# Command line layout with CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make an useful command-line layout just using CSS. My inkscape draft looks like this:

[image: command line layout]

The bottom `div` has a fixed height and flexible width. The top `div` must have both dimensions flexible.

I need this to work on *mobile devicest* too. In past, [I have made this design](http://u8.8u.cz/demo/) using rather complicated javascript script which breaks on mobile devices.

I've been [trying to do it](http://jsfiddle.net/Darker/081tcm3m/) using height in "%" but that's not very precise I guess:

```
div#output {
  width:99%;
  height:90%; //NOT A GOOD IDEA. DEPENDS ON WINDOW SIZE
  overflow: scroll;//             - breaks on big/small screens                                   
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin:0px;
  padding:5px;
}
```

**My question is:** How to do this with no javascript? How should I fix my jsFiddle example?

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: That's nice. Good luck with that. Did you have a question?

Comment: Yes, how to do it without javascript. Is that not a question?

Comment: @TomášZato Well you didn't initially have it in there, so there was originally no question. There is now.

Comment: @ajp15243 The final question is just a summary of what is in the text. I expected SO users to read whole my post and understand it. If any part of it is poorly written and therefore hard to understand, feel free to use the *Edit* button.

Comment: @TomášZato To be honest, I had no idea what your question was before you put it in, so I couldn't use the Edit button. I'm not trying to be hostile, I'm just trying to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use calc for the height of the output window here is the [updated JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/081tcm3m/2/)

```
*{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px; 
}
html, body {
    height:100%; 
}
body {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size:0;
}
div#output {
    height:calc(100% - 40px);
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding:5px;
    font-size:14px;
}
div#bottom{
    height:30px;
    line-height:30px;
    font-size:14px;
}
```

The font-size:0 for the body is necessary to remove redundant spaces between the two DIVs.
Calc is subtracting 40px since the bottom is 30px and the output has a padding of 5px.

without using Calc is also possible with absolute positioning [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/081tcm3m/3/)

```
*{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px; 
}
html, body {
    height:100%; 
}
body {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size:0;
}
div#output {
    position:absolute;
    top:5px;
    left:5px;
    right:5px;
    bottom:30px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    font-size:14px;
}
div#bottom{
    position:absolute;
    left:5px;
    bottom:0;
    height:30px;
    line-height:30px;
    font-size:14px;
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a good idea. But couldn't I actually avoid `calc` by using `padding` for *output* and `position:absoulute` for *input*?

Comment: Actually you can, I have updated the Fiddle [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/081tcm3m/3/)

Comment: Wery cool, thanks. I hope this will be useful for others too.

Answer (score 0):

Set the height of the html and body to 100%. That is what the 90% is scaling against.

Comment: If a `<body>` has 100% width, does that always mean 100% screen size?

Comment: It means it has the width of the parent, which is the HTML tag. Im not exactly sure how that ends up translating out to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this http://jsfiddle.net/081tcm3m/1/

There is no need to set `width` to block elements. It's the `height` important here. Setting it to `100%` to body makes page fit the available screen height (if there is no margin).

**edit**

You are right, dimensions in `%` are not precise, so I decided to use position `absolute` and `right`, `left`, `top`, `bottom` properties to stretch `div#output` and make fixed margin for bottom input line.

Try http://jsfiddle.net/081tcm3m/4/

Comment: Thank you. But try to resize the output window of your fiddle. That's why I was saying that `%` height is not very precise. It depends on window size.